# PHP routing and stylesheets

Tags: php, css, directory-structure

I'm trying to learn something about MVC, but I have problems including stylesheets correctly.

In my `index.php` I do `require_once('views/layout.php');`. Now I want to include my `main.css` which is placed at `css/main.css`, but I can't figure out how I could do that correctly, since the urls look like this: `example.com/controller/action` and the browser tries to load my stylesheets from `example.com/controller/css/main.css`

Now I could include the stylesheets like this: `<link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">`, but I don't think that this would be a good solution, since that wouldn't work with urls like `example.com/controller/action/1`.

I'd like to know if there's a good way to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have a global variable name:

`$rootUrl = 'https://yourdomain.com';`

So wherever I need include style/script file, I use absolute path:

```
<script src="<?php echo $rootUrl . '/css/main.css' ?>" /><script>
```